# Compare revenue and outgo with JavaScript

Tags: javascript, html

I want when the submit button is clicked, Compare the amount of income and expenses and the result will be displayed as a pop-up.

But it does not work. Where do you think the problem

```js
var income = document.getElementById('income').value;
var outgo = document.getElementById('outgo').value;

function incomeCalculation() {
    if (income > outgo) {
        alert('income > outgo');
    } else if (outgo > income) {
       alert('outgo > income');
    }
}
```

```html
    <label>Income:</label>
    <input type="text" id="income">
    <br><br>
    <label>Outgo:&nbsp;&nbsp;</label>
    <input type="text" id="outgo">
    <br><br>
    <input type="submit" id="submit" onclick="incomeCalculation()">
```

Comment: Your input values will be strings, you need to parse them as numbers before comparing them.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are a couple of problems here:

- You need to parse your inputs as numbers, as inputs will return `string` values. (Use either `parseFloat` or `parseInt`)
- You want to get the values when the button is clicked, not when the document loads, so the variables should be set inside the function.

```js
function incomeCalculation() {
  var income = parseFloat(document.getElementById('income').value);
  var outgo = parseFloat(document.getElementById('outgo').value);

  if (income > outgo) {
    alert('income > outgo');
  } else if (outgo > income) {
    alert('outgo > income');
  }
}
```

```html
<label>Income:</label>
<input type="text" id="income">
<br><br>
<label>Outgo:&nbsp;&nbsp;</label>
<input type="text" id="outgo">
<br><br>
<input type="submit" id="submit" onclick="incomeCalculation()">
```

Answer (score 1):

```
function incomeCalculation() {
    var income = document.getElementById('income').value;
    var outgo = document.getElementById('outgo').value;

    if (income > outgo) {
        alert('income > outgo');
    } else if (outgo > income) {
       alert('outgo > income');
    }
}
```